# Pycharm Import file not found - SeleniumLibrary

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, import, pycharm, robotframework

I am quite new to this pycharm/robotframework/selenium thing and I went through all the questions here but I am not able to find a solution to my issue.

2 weeks ago my scripts were working fine, but now I always get a warning that "Import file not found", so I am not able to run my scripts.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem I am not able to figure that out...

Settings:
Windows 10
Python 3.11
Pycharm Community Edition 2022.2.1.
IntelliBot #patched: 0.15.191.8026

**PIP - LIST:**
| Package | Version |
| ------- | ------- |
| async-generator | 1.10 |
| attrs | 22.1.0 |
| certifi | 2022.9.24 |
| cffi | 1.15.1 |
| h11 | 0.14.0 |
| idna | 3.4 |
| outcome | 1.2.0 |
| pip | 22.3 |
| pycparser | 2.21 |
| PySocks | 1.7.1 |
| robotframework | 6.0 |
| robotframework-pythonlibcore | 3.0.0 |
| robotframework-seleniumlibrary | 6.0.0 |
| selenium | 4.5.0 |
| setuptools | 65.5.0 |
| sniffio | 1.3.0 |
| sortedcontainers | 2.4.0 |
| trio | 0.22.0 |
| trio-websocket | 0.9.2 |
| urllib3 | 1.26.12 |
| wsproto | 1.2.0 |

Can you please have a look at my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be facing an issue that your current python version is unable to access the required packages. Making even reinstalling the required packages useless.

If you have upgraded your python version in recently this might be your answer.

I use VScode, so I dont know how to fix this in Pycharm, but you might search how to select the python interpreter you want, and select the old version